# Pyramid Traversal __name__ matching a view name

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid, traversal, dom-traversal

In a Traversal pyramid app, how does one handle a resource w/ a `__name__` that matches a view's name?

If I wanted to get to the view callable "view" for a Resource, I'd use a URL path like:`/foo/bar/view`. It traverses the resource_tree as so:

```
RootFactory(request) => RootFactory
RootFactory['foo']   => Foo
Foo['bar']           => Bar
Bar['view']          => KeyError
```

...and because it can't traverse past Bar & 'view' is left over, it assumes that 'view' is the view name, and matches to my view callable

```
@view_config(name='view')
def view(context, request):
    return Response(context.__name__)
```

To get the URL for that path I'd use `request.resource_url(resource, "view"`).

However, if I had a resource such that `Bar.__name__ = "view"`, how can I resolve a URL for "view" on Foo?

```
# path: /foo/view
RootFactory(request) => RootFactory
RootFactory['foo']   => Foo  # ideally stop here with view_name="view"
Foo['view']          => Bar.__name__ = "view"
# all parts of path matched so view_name="" and context=Bar
```

Ideally, in this situation, `/foo/view` would point to `view(Foo, request)`, and `/foo/view/view` would point to `view(Bar, request)` where `Bar.__name__ == "view"`.

Is there a way to handle this without writing detection for collisions between `__name__` and view names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I wound up at is adding an arbitrary layer of container resources.

Below is an example structure of the resources:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = name

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "bar":
            return BarContainer(self, "bar")
        else:
            raise KeyError()

class BarContainer(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = name

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return Bar(self, key)

class Bar(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        self.__parent__ = parent
        self.__name__ = name
```

The question mentions wanting to generate resource URLs to the view callable titled view. With `BarContainer` this just adds an extra slash:

```
/{foo}/bar/{bar}/<view_name>    
/a/view          => view(context=Foo(name='a'), request)
/a/bar/view      => view(context=BarContainer(name='bar'), request)
/a/bar/b/view    => view(context=Bar(name='b'), request)
```